# Kraken API with a PHP script causes HTML page to go blank

Tags: php, html, api, streaming

Does anyone see a problem with this HTML/PHP code? as soon as i added it, the page showed as blank, with the browser not reading any source code at all. Even if i comment it out with  it still is blank!

```
<body>
<?php

function getInfo ($a)
{

$online = 'images/streamRing/online.png';
$offline = 'images/streamRing/offline.png';
$size = '20';

$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'.strtolower($a)), true);

if ($array['stream'] != NULL)
{
$channelTitle = $array['stream']['channel']['display_name'];
$streamTitle = $array['stream']['channel']['status'];
$currentGame = $array['stream']['channel']['game'];

echo "<tr><td class='onlineStatus'><img src='$online' height='$size' width='$size' alt='Online' />Online</td>";
echo "<td>$channelTitle</td><td>$streamTitle</td></tr>";
}
else
{
echo "<tr><td class='onlineStatus'><img src='$offline' height='$size' width='$size' alt='Offline' />Offline</td>";
echo "<td>$a</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
}
}

?>
```

.... (later in the page...) ....

```
<table class="onlineList">
<th>
<td class="onlineStatus"><h3>Status</h3></td>
<td><h3>Streamer Name</h3></td>
<td><h3>Stream Title</h3></td>
</th>


<?php
$streamer_1 = 'xxxx';
$streamer_2 = 'yyyy';

getInfo($streamer_2);
getInfo($streamer_1);
?>

</table>
```

The php code was developed using Kraken API, which is demonstrated rather simply here:
http://www.incendiarymedia.org/twitch/status.php

Edit: I noticed and fixed the breaking error. I used double quotes within a php echo, which is..... bad! However, the code still has an error. The table shows the headers, then the individual cells are misaligned. Somehow the images for the first column show up to the LEFT of the first column header. I don't see why!

Comment: hey, you didn't escape double quotes! Your PHP couldn't run at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is invalid table markup

```
<table class="onlineList">
<th>
<td class="onlineStatus"><h3>Status</h3></td>
<td><h3>Streamer Name</h3></td>
<td><h3>Stream Title</h3></td>
</th>
```

The `<th>` element behaves like a cell, but you are using it like a row instead of `<tr>`

Try this:

```
<table class="onlineList">
<tr>
<td class="onlineStatus"><h3>Status</h3></td>
<td><h3>Streamer Name</h3></td>
<td><h3>Stream Title</h3></td>
</tr>
```